# Why can't it show up on Search in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

My question is: I want to ask if I search for "Computer Science" and the "Programming Language" subLayer section appears but if you search for sections in the subLayer such as "HTML" and "CSS" it doesn't appear or can't, why is that? And what needs to be fixed from my coding in reactJS?

This is my json file:

```
layers :[
    {
      key: "1",
      title: "Computer Science",
      expanded: false,
      subLayer: [
        {
          key: "a",
          title: "Programming Language",
          expanded: false,
          subLayer: [
            {
              key: "a.1",
              title: "HTML",
              expanded: false,
              subLayer: [],
            },
            {
              key: "a.2",
              title: "CSS",
              expanded: false,
              subLayer: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

Code:

```
import data from './Data'

const checked = (e) => { }

function List(props) {
  const filteredData = data.layers.filter((el) => {
    if (props.input === '') {
      return el
    }
    return el.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input) || el.subLayer.findIndex(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)) >= 0
  }) 

  return (
    <Accordion allowMultipleExpanded allowZeroExpanded className="text-sm">
      {filteredData.map((list) => (
        <AccordionItem key={list.key}>
          <AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemButton>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="mx-2 text-sm"
                value="false"
                onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                onChange={checked}
              />
              {list.title}
              <WorkspacesIcon className="WorkspacesIcons" />
            </AccordionItemButton>
          </AccordionItemHeading>
          <AccordionItemPanel>
            {list.subLayer.length !== 0 ? (
              <>
                {list.subLayer.map((listDetails) => (
                  <Accordion allowMultipleExpanded allowZeroExpanded>
                    <AccordionItem>
                      <AccordionItemHeading>
                        <AccordionItemButton>
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            className="mx-2"
                            value="false"
                            onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                            onChange={checked}
                          />
                          {listDetails.title}
                        </AccordionItemButton>
                      </AccordionItemHeading>
                      <AccordionItemPanel />
                      <AccordionItemPanel>
                        {listDetails.subLayer.length !== 0 ? (
                          <>
                            {listDetails.subLayer.map((listDetails1) => (
                              <AccordionItem>
                                <AccordionItemHeading>
                                  <AccordionItemButton>
                                    <input
                                      type="checkbox"
                                      className="mx-2"
                                      value="false"
                                      onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                                      onChange={checked}
                                    />
                                    {listDetails1.title}
                                  </AccordionItemButton>
                                </AccordionItemHeading>
                                <AccordionItemPanel />
                              </AccordionItem>
                            ))}
                          </>
                        ) : (
                          ''
                        )}
                      </AccordionItemPanel>
                    </AccordionItem>
                  </Accordion>
                ))}
              </>
            ) : (
              ''
            )}
          </AccordionItemPanel>
        </AccordionItem>
      ))}
    </Accordion>
  )
}
```

Images:
[image]

if i write my code reactJS part `filteredData`, is there any error in this part:

```
const filteredData = data.layers.filter((el) => {
    if (props.input === '') {
      return el
    }
    return el.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input) || el.subLayer.findIndex(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)) >= 0
  })
```

Comment: Can you provide codesandbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are just filtering based on the first layer title (eg: Computer Science) and the first sublayer title (eg: Programming language) only. You need to add another condition to look for the second sublayer.
Based on your code your return line would be:

```
return el.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input) || el.subLayer.findIndex(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)) >= 0 || el.subLayer[0].subLayer.findIndex(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)) >= 0
```

To make more dynamic for when you have multiple arrays you can do this:

```
  return (
      el.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input.toLowerCase()) ||
      el.subLayer.findIndex((x) => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input.toLowerCase())) >= 0 ||
      el.subLayer
        .map(
          (x) =>
            x.subLayer.findIndex((x) => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input.toLowerCase())) >= 0,
        )
        .includes(true)
    )
```

Comment: I use this code to add : ` || el.subLayer.subLayer.findIndex(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)) >= 0 ` but error and not showing

Comment: Based on the your data structure the second one will be el.subLayer[0].subLayer.find etc..

Comment: @FizMe You will probably need a more solid algorithm to map all the arrays if you have many, do you need help with that as well?

Comment: you can use recursion until you find the last node/record

Comment: @FizMe I updated the answer with a more dynamic algorithm, for when you have multiple subLayers! Hope this helps